# Ajax settimeout to read status from php/mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get Ajaz to pull data from mysql using a php file every 5 seconds and the process continues.  It seems to work great in firefox but does not update in IE.

Can anyone help make this platform independent?

Ajax/Jquery Code

```
function startprogress() {
    $.get("status.php");
    setTimeout('updateStatus()', 500);
}

function updateStatus() {
    $("#progress").load("status.php");
    setTimeout('updateStatus()', 500);
}
```

PHP File

```
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","password") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db("table");

 $sql="SELECT current, total FROM status WHERE id = 1";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
     echo "Completed: " . $row['current'] ." of " . $row['total'];
    }
```

Then I have an empty div with id of progress in my HTML file where I have the onClick event to trigger the startprogress() function.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks much.

Comment: If you want live stuff, you should check something like websocket/node. Also, i think you should use setInterval() instead.

Comment: Switched to setInterval.  Worked great but does not stop when the script is done until I refresh the browser.  It works for my purpose though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use setInterval you should do something like this:

```
var id = setInterval(function() {
   // Do something each interval
}, 1000);


clearInterval(id); // When you want to clear it
```

Some exemple [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval) and [here](http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Guide-to-JavaScript-Timers-with-setTimeout-and-setInterval).